# How to Put an IF statement inside a Loop

Tags: php

OK so I have this loop, I want to change the value if the loop lands on a certain value. for example in the code below, $p will equal 15 for Tier2. but when running the script nothing happens, it just runs as normal and ignores my if statement.

```
$get_sponsor = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT sponsor FROM ap_members WHERE id=$affiliate_id"));
$sponsor = $get_sponsor['sponsor'];
for ($loop = 2 ; $loop < $levels; $loop++){ 

    //CHECK FOR AVAILABLE SPONSOR
    if($sponsor!='0'){

        //GET LEVEL PERCENTAGE
        $gp = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ap_other_commissions WHERE id=1"));
        $p = $gp['tier'.$loop.'']; 
            if($p == 15){ // changes for custom override
                $sc = $tier2_com / 100;
            } else {
                $sc = $p / 100;
            }
        $se = $sale_amount * $sc;
```

Comment: Well, `if` statements aren't simply ignored. Have you verified your condition actually behaves as you expect?

Comment: Try comparing with string like this. `if($p == '15')`

Comment: hey why u not check your if condition out of for loop ..

Comment: You can probably do what ever you are trying to do with 1 query. Could you add more detail about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik since PHP is loosely typed, `==15` and `=='15'` mean the same thing...

Comment: @chris85 - ok so the loop goes through 10 levels / tiers - I am trying to stop it at tier2 to change the value it gives via a dynamic variable instead of the set value in the database.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - yes the values come out how I want it to without using it inside of the loop.  all it is doing is taking 2 values from a database, subtracting them to get the new variable then dividing it by 100. to get the percentage value. maybe I need to try a different way to stop the loop..

Answer (score 0):

```
   //GET LEVEL PERCENTAGE
                $gp = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ap_other_commissions WHERE id=1"));
                $p = $gp['tier'.$loop.'']; 
                    if($loop == 2){ // changes for custom override
                        $p = $tier2_com;
                        $sc = $tier2_com / 100;
                    } else {
                        $sc = $p / 100;
                    }
                $se = $sale_amount * $sc;
```

I released that i was missing the $p in the if statement to give to update it correctly in the database.  all is working now.. thanks for the suggestions guys.